# Regex replace with string that contains a character from the origianal

Tags: c#, regex

Can Regex replace a pattern in a string with another string that contains a character from the original? For example:

> X(#2(**3**)) -> X([0-9]{**3**})[0-9]*
>
> X(#6(**1**)) -> X([0-9]{**1**})[0-9]*
>
> X(#9(**4**)) -> X([0-9]{**4**})[0-9]*

In each case, the bolded number is placed in the new string. Is this possible to do with Regex? If not, what can be an efficient solution for this?

Comment: Are you asking if regex can do a find and replace?

Comment: Yes, with variables.

Comment: Your sample text suggests you already know the answer. There is a link on SO for regex FAQ's if you have any other general questions.

Comment: How does my sample text suggest that I know how to code it?

Comment: I'm guessing because of this `X([0-9]{3})[0-9]*`

Comment: Funny how close my sample text was to the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible with regex using capturing group.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"X\(#\d+\((\d+)\)\)", "X([0-9]{$1})[0-9]*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vQ4tX9/3)